# Mechanize (Download to custom directory)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm curious to know how I can download a file from the web to a specific directory on my machine using the Mechanize module in Python. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading a file to a custom directory with mechanize is as simple as:

```
import mechanize

FILE_URL = 'http://mit.edu/img/MIT_logo.gif'
DESTINATION = '/tmp/lol.gif'

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.retrieve(FILE_URL, DESTINATION)
```

After running this, you'll find MIT's logo saved as lol.gif in the /tmp/ directory.